# How can we generate/encode barcode image without border using zxing library in .net code?

Tags: c#, .net, zxing, zxing.net

How to generate barcode image without border using zxing library.So how to generate it without the border property in .net code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet shows a way to generate an image without a border:

```
            var writer = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter
            {
                Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
                {
                    Height = 0,
                    Width = 0,
                    Margin = 0
                },
            };
            var barcodeImage = writer.Write("<your content here>");
```

But you have to scale the image manually. ZXing.Net only supports scaling without anti-aliasing, so it can't stretch it to a given height and width without border if the scaling factor isn't an integer.

But you should be careful with barcode images without borders. For example, the QR specification defines a quiet zone (white border) with a size of four modules. If there is no quiet zone it could happen that not every reader can decode it.